# Database data is not an array or object

Tags: php, laravel

I want to print '$post' as an array from database.

```
<tbody>
            @if (is_array($posts) || is_object($posts)){
                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{$post->id }}</th>
                    <td>{{$post->title }}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->body }}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->created_at }}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">View</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach

            @else
                {{'no!'}}
            @endif
            </tbody>
```

it just prints no! this is the main function:

```
    public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();

    return view('posts.index')->withPosts('$posts');
}
```

Comment: why can't you check like this i.e.. $posts = Post::all()->toArray();

Comment: is `->withPosts` a valid statement?

Comment: @DPS I checked it did not work, the solution was :
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();

    return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));

}

Answer (score 3):

You should below way to pass the data from view file.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();

    return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));

}
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you

Comment: @Pali Glad to help you. Feel free to accept this as answer if our solution addressed your concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get method , get will return all of the results in the model's table. After that you can pass the result to your view.

```
public function index(){
$posts = Post::get();

return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.